# How can I start to fully communicate with hardware in languages such as C, Python and Assembly?

Tags: graphics, input, hardware, microcontroller

The one thing I haven't been able to find tutorials for on the internet, is actually communicating with hardware. The following is what I really want to be able to do:

Be able to communicate with the graphics card to create graphics

Communicate with the keyboard

Communicate with a built in or external voice recognition speaker and also the same with a web cam

The problem is is that I haven't been able to find tutorials for this sort of thing- actually communicating with computer components. And I don't just mean using a library that's already been like Pygame of Open Gl, I mean doing this from scratch.

How can I go about communicating with all types of hardware- whether they're built in the computer, connected via ports using a cable, or even wireless- preferably using python3 or c or assembly? Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm just feeling very aimless right now and I need to do something productive with my programming. I've tried searching on Google for answers but to no avail.

Comment: Get yourself a small embedded micro-controller board and do some "bare metal" programming.

Comment: You'll need to study the drivers and become one with `ioctl`

Comment: Please don't cross-post (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/215653/7043).

Comment: @delnan I deleted the original.

Comment: @Paul R I've heard of this Arduino microcontroller. Would that be a good place to start. What about the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes, either the Arduino or the Raspberry Pi is good, although both of these have operating systems - if you really want to start from scratch you can just get any micro-controller evaluation board and start coding from the ground up.

Comment: @Paul R If it didn't have an OS, would I then have to create my own  to start using the microcontroller? Do you any popular microcontroller evaluation boards that don't have a built in OS?

Comment: @83457, there's no reason to use an OS if you don't want to. Plenty of microcontroller-controlled devices just have a big `while (1)` loop.

Comment: As @Carl says, no need for an OS - that's what "bare metal" programming *is* - writing code that runs directly on the hardware without any intervening OS. There are plenty to choose from: PIC, ARM/Cortex, 8051, etc.

Comment: if you have not been able to find out how do do these things in C for example you really have not started to look.  Keep looking, very easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're writing bare-metal software of some kind (an operating system, a bootloader, or maybe a standalone application on a microcontroller), none of these operations are things you can do "from scratch".  You will need to rely on the operating-system-provided interfaces to control them.

Edit:  If you want to do bare-metal control, you'll need to get the appropriate data sheet for whatever device you're programming and read it for details of how to control the various peripherals you're interested in.  On a lot of microcontroller platforms, the peripherals are [memory-mapped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O), meaning you just write patterns of bits as defined by the data sheet to various specific physical memory addresses to cause various operations to happen.

Comment: What you've described is precisely what i'd like to do, the phrasing of my question could've been the cause of misunderstanding. Do you know how I could go about this bare-metal stuff?

Comment: Start programming for a microcontroller (e.g, an Arduino), not a desktop computer.

Comment: Intel's released a dev board ["Galileo"](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/do-it-yourself/galileo-maker-quark-board.html)  for the maker/hobbyist market. That's another option.